# Foreign key constraint issue in JPA despite "cascade all" being present

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to delete entities of type "LearnItem"

```
@Entity
public class LearnItem implements Comparable<LearnItem>, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526471111622776111L;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="learnItem", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
protected List<StudentItemRecord> studentItemRecords;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="learnItem", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
protected List<Result> results;
}
```

However, I get a *"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wcdtg7jkp873w8ob`.`student_item_record`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ockk47ux0gb08lnuisradomer` FOREIGN KEY (`learn_item_id`) REFERENCES `learn_item` (`id`))"* error.
In StudentItemRecord, I have a reference for LearnItem:

```
@ManyToOne
private LearnItem learnItem;
```

I don't know why I get this error, isn't the CascadeType.ALL setting supposed to delete all StudentItemRecords in the list, avoiding the foreign key constraint issue?

Comment: You're probably deleting a LearnItem that hasn't been properly populated with its list of student records. WIthout code, hard to tell more.

Comment: What does it mean properly populated?

Comment: Are you calling EntityManager.remove(), using a Repository or a query?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your database schema. The JPA configuration will not overwrite your DB schema, so if you're restricting the delete in JPA it'll not delete all the dependencies by default.

Or for example you  might have a dependency like this:

```
A -> B -> C

A -> B = Cascade
B -> C = Cascade
```

In this situation, if you delete A, B and C will be deleted.
If instead in the DB, you have

```
A -> B = Cascade
B -> C = Restrict
```

Nothing will be deleted because the FK between B and C will prevent it.